# How to build an application layer pre-fetching system

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, caching, prefetch

I'm working in a C/C++ mixed project that has the following situation.

I need to have a iteration to go through very small chunks (rarely larger chunks as well) in a file one by one. Ideally, I should just read them once consecutively.  I think will be a better solution in this case to read a big chunk into a buffer and consume it later, rather than read each of them instantly when I need.

The problem is, how do I balance the cache size?  Is there any well-known algorithm/library that I can take advantage of?

---

UPDATE: (changes the title)

Thanks for you guys' replies and I understand there are different levels of caching mechanism working in our boxes. But that not enough in my case.

I think I missed something important here. Actually I'm building an application upon an existing framework, in which requesting reads to the engine frquently will cost too much for me. (Yes, i believe the engine do take advantage of OS and disk level caches.) And what I'm trying to do is indeed to build an application level pre-fetching system.

Thoughts?

Comment: This probably isn't something worth worrying about, unless you have constant reads going on all over the place. Disks can cache a lot of data; I think up to 64 MB, generally, and they will often pull more than what you requested into the cache. That aside, I would suggest pulling in a sector worth of data (probably 2 or 4 KB).

Comment: Modern OSes use all free memory as disk cache, not just 64MB.

Comment: Maybe I should have said 'disk buffer,' I was referring to the hardware embedded in the drive.

Comment: @BatchyX: Extremely true. If I copy an 8 GB zip file from my `C` to `D` drives it maxes out at ~80 MB/s, then from `D` to `E`, it maxes out at the interface speed (something like 300 MB/s).

Comment: so it's not file reading at all, is it?  why is the word "file" in the title?  suspect i still don't understand.  also, while i am here, is "cache" the right word?  this is really just pre-fetching isn't it?  will you ever read the data a second time?  (difference being that in this case you expire data on read).

Comment: @andrewcooke thanks for pointing this out. from what it's said on wikipedia, cache is not the right word here, and file as well. Sorry for misleading you guys, this is good lesson for me to understand how to set a right title for questions.

Comment: no problem.  often the problem is knowing which word to google :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general you should try to use what the OS gives you, rather than creating your own cache (because you run the risk of caching twice).  for linux, you can request OS level caching via [readahead()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readahead); i don't know what the windows equivalent would be.

looking into this some more, there is also a block level (ie disk) parameter, set via [blockdev --setra](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_blockdev.htm).  it's probably not a good idea to change that on your system (unless it is dedicated to just this one task), but if the value there (blockdev --getra) is already larger than your typical chunk size then you may not need to do anything else.

[and just to address the other point mentioned in the question comments - while an OS will cache file data in free memory, i don't believe that it will pre-emptively read an otherwise unread file (apart from to meet the requirements above).  but if anyone knows otherwise, please post details...]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the OS level cache is not enough in my case, please refer to my update in the question.

Comment: is this anything like what you're after - http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1251047 (i got that by searching for "pre-fetch memory management heuristic" - i think "cache" is not helping here).

Comment: Thanks for that! Will do research on this and get back here later.

Comment: i'd suggest starting a new q if you have more questions as more people will see it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `mmap()`ing the file instead of `read()`ing from it? In some cases this might be more efficient, in some cases this might not. However it is usually best to let the system optimize for you, since it knows more about the hardware than an application. `mmap()` will let the system know that you need the whole file, so it might just be more optimal.

Comment: actually i'm not reading files on my own, sorry for misleading you here. please refer to my update in the question

Comment: @Reinhard: So if I understand it correctly, the application issues the reads to a framework and the framework itself handles the system level access to the data? And now you want to find a better way to cache the data from the framework and not from the system itself? In that case I think it is possible to answer your question, since this is highly dependent on the framework itself. You better ask the people who have written the framework directly on good ways to handle this, since they are the only ones able to help you out here.